# livewire updates causing error in x-data nested within x-if / x-for

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a problem using AlpineJs, combined with Livewire updates. Consider this simplified code placed within a livewire component:

```
<input type="text" wire:model="name" />

<template x-if="newItem">
    <div x-data="{
        open: false,
    }">
        <div x-text="open"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Typing on the text input causes the following error after the roundtrip to the server.

```
SupportAlpine.js:294 Alpine Expression Error: Illegal invocation
Expression: "open"
```

I also have observed a similar behavior using x-for directive.

Right now, I am using two workarounds. Either I use x-show instead of x-if, and, when it is not possible, I use the x-init directive. In fact, this code doesn't produce the same error:

```
<input type="text" wire:model="name" />

<template x-if="newDossier">
    <div x-data="{
        id: 'dossierSearch',
        open: false,
        resultsFn: 'searchDossiers',
        searchText: ''
    }" x-init="this.open=false; this.searchText = ''">
        <div x-text="open"></div>
        <input x-model="searchText" />
    </div>
</template>
```

However, I would like to know if there is some way to make it work without using workarounds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Livewire version are you using?

Comment: 2.12. I am willing to update to v3, but, since folder structure was changed, I am avoiding it for now.